# HTML5 Canvas - What's the simplest way to draw a line that gets thicker and thicker to the end?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

What's the simplest way to draw a line that gets thicker and thicker to the end?
Like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/D3Sjz6Z]

And this is for a clock project so I want the line x and y points not to be constant, I mean that the line should spin around a point using sinus and cosinus no ctx.rotate only MATH.

Simply, how can I also make the line spin around the black spot?

Comment: What do you got so far?

Comment: A line that gets thicker and thicker to the end is commonly called a triangle or a 3 sided polygon.

Comment: Yeah whatever you call it doesn't matter but you get the picture right? Sooo, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Mich try an arc ? I made example in http://jsfiddle.net/jwR8C/

Comment: It's great, but the problem is that the spinning axis is at the top and not the bottom...

Comment: how about using an image ;)

Comment: why don't you want to use context rotation?  It would make the math far simpler...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For HTML5 canvas with its origin at top left, the general formulae for a point rotated *clockwise from vertical* are:

```
var x = cx + r * Math.sin(theta);
var y = cy - r * Math.cos(theta);
```

Where `[cx, cy]` is the center point of your clock, and `theta` is measured in radians.

For your clock handle, just use these formulae three (or four) times, depending on whether you want the handle to end at a point (i.e. a triangle) or at a line (i.e. a parallelogram).

Calculate `theta` based on the required time, and then for each point adjust it (and pick suitable `r`) for the required shape.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/NgQWH/ for a demo

Comment: @Mich here's a "more final" version of my own clock - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/kKTka/